# Strange behavior of python's pandas.merge

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a left merge between two data base, the left db has 36000 rows, 406 columns; while the right db has 23x13 in dimension. The key composes of two (object) columns, and with no duplicates in the right db.

Those two data base are created after a long code. If I merge those data, it takes 4 seconds, which is anormally slow. If I saved those data base in csv, then read them again, and do exactly the same merge, it takes only 300ms.

I am currently not able to make a reproducible without publicing the data.

Comment: Interesting. What if you make copies of each dataframe and then merge those two copies?  Using df_1c = df_1.copy() and df_2c = df_2.copy().

Comment: @ScottBoston it does not improve the performance. I checked the RAM, I still have 8GB available.

Comment: Do you have a datetime dtype?  My guess maybe you are converting datetime to string and the string is joining faster than datetime?

Comment: The key are pure string type, not datetime, but in my left db, there are plenty of datetime types other than the keys.